# How to stub an incoming http request (response) with cypress

Tags: javascript, http, request, cypress, intercept

How can I stub a response of a HTTP request?

Let me explain it with my code I have now:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("FakeLoginWithMsal", (userId) => {
   
    cy.intercept('**/oauth2/v2.0/token', (req) => {
        
        req.reply({
            token_type: "Bearer",
            expires_in: 3795,
            access_token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJS"
            })

        req.continue((res) => {

        })
    })
```

With this code I am trying to stub the response for the following request:

[image]

But it still gives the following error, where I can understand the stub did not work:

> We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request
> failed without a response.

I've tried already different intercept methods of cypress but I couldn't get worked.

---

I even can't intercept the /token endpoint with the following:

```
   cy.intercept({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xx-xx-xx-xx-/oauth2/v2.0/token',
}).as('apiCheck')
```

[image]

---

Update:
@Fody Thankyou vey much (again) for you respond. Actually I am trying to stub all the MSAL endpoints. It is not a testscript, but a login command.

Here it is:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("FakeLoginWithMsal", (userId) => {
    cy.intercept('GET', '**/authorize', { fixture: 'authorizeStub.json' })
    cy.intercept('GET', '**/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration', { fixture: 'openidConfigurationStub.json' })

cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    body: {
        grant_type: "password",
        client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        client_secret: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        scope: "api://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Cp.Use",
        username: "xxx@xxxx.com",
        password: "xxxxx",
    },
    form: true,
}).then(response => {
    cy.log(JSON.stringify(response))
    cy.intercept('response', { fixture: 'tokenStub.json' })

    })
```

These are 3 endpoints, namely:

GET: /authorize  (stubbed with a fixture)

GET: /openid-configuration (stubbed with a fixture)

Post: /token --> This POST has a response and there inside is the accesstoken. **This response I need to stub.**

[image]

And I guess that this response is a "incoming HTTP request" (see attachments). This incoming http response is exactly what I want to stub in a fixture.

Comment: Hi. In the code snippet, you are stubbing for `**/oauth2/v2.0/token` route, however there are no matched requests in the screenshot for it.

Comment: Thankyou for you input, it looks like I cant intercept the /token endpoint. I'm really curiouse what I am doing wrong. I've updated the question with a new try while I am using the whole endpoint url.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure without seeing the whole test, but are you are issuing the POST to microsoftonline from within the test using `cy.request()`?

If so, you can't use `cy.intercept()` to catch it, only requests from the app will be caught.

But you can append a `.then()` to the `cy.request()` to wait for the response.

```js
cy.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/.../oauth2/v2.0/token',
})
.then(response => {
  // handle response
  
})
```

---

Also in this code `req.reply()` and `req.continue()` you are both stubbing (with reply) and continuing to the server (with continue), which are opposite actions. You would only want to do one or the other.

```js
cy.intercept('**/oauth2/v2.0/token', (req) => {
        
  req.reply({
    token_type: "Bearer",
    expires_in: 3795,
    access_token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJS"
  })

  req.continue((res) => {

  })
})
```

Comment: Hi Fody! Thankyou very much (again) for you help. I understand your answer but I am not sure that this is what I need. I have updated my question, would you like to check the last section of the question.

Comment: Hi, no problem - any chance you can show the test code?

Comment: Here it is. I also updated the question above. 

Cypress.Commands.add("FakeLoginWithMsal", (userId) => {
     
    cy.intercept('GET', '**/authorize', { fixture: 'authorizeStub.json' })
    cy.intercept('GET', '**/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration', { fixture: 'openidConfigurationStub.json' })
    cy.intercept('POST','**/oauth2/v2.0/token', (req) => {
        // Here I'm trying to stub the response of the POST: /token 
        req.reply({
            token_type: "Bearer",
            expires_in: 3795,
            access_token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJS"
        })

    })

Comment: That's the custom command, but I was hoping to see the test where it is used - the `it()` block.

Comment: Yes Fody you are correct. it is the custom command. There is no test related to it. This command I want to use for offline login with MSAL. I have implemented your cy.request() suggestion and now I have a good response. But when I am offline, there is a no correct response. And exactly when I am offline, I want to stub a correct response :).

Would you like check the updated question of mine?

Comment: Actually, I wasn't suggesting you use `cy.request()` - just if you did use it the `cy.intercept()` cannot see it.

Comment: ah! I just understand you better now, this make it clear for me! Because the request was indeed sendout with a cy.request!  Can we add a static response with a .then() to the cy.request() ?